# How to solve this equation : $(k + k+1 + k+2 +\ldots n) + (k+1 + k+2 + \ldots n) + (k+2 + \ldots n) + \ldots n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> How to solve this equation : $(k + k+1 + k+2 +\ldots n) + (k+1 + k+2 + \ldots n) + (k+2 + \ldots n) + \ldots n$

Example: 
$k = 3$, $n =5$: $(3+4+5) + (4+5) + (5) = ??$

Is there any formula to solve this kind of summation? 
If not, can this be solve in less than linear time?

Please help with your inputs.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you have $n-k+1$ times $n$, $n-k+1-1$ times $n-1$, ... , $2$ times $k+1$, and once $k$. Generically, you have $j-k+1$ times $j$. So the sum of all terms is

$$
\sum_{j = k}^n j \cdot (j-k+1)
$$

This can be summed to give

$$
\frac16 (n+2-k)(n+1-k)(k + 2 n)
$$

Answer (score 4):

Write it with sums:
$$\sum_{i=k}^n \sum_{j = i}^n j.$$
Now the inner sum should look familiar to you, and you get
$$\sum_{i=k}^n \frac{n(n+1) - i(i-1)}{2}.$$

To compute this outer sum, you might want to use formulas for
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2,$$
that you will find in most undergraduate textbooks and will have most likely already shown for yourself.

Hint: The final value should be a polynomial of degree three in $n$, minus a polynomial of degree three in $k$.